# Passing helper text to redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using redux-form 6.0.0-rc.4 and I'm wondering if there's a way to pass an additional property to my `Field`s.

Here's my `renderField` component:

```
const renderField = field => (
  <div className={field.touched && field.error ? 'invalid' : 'valid'}>
    <label>{field.input.placeholder}</label>
    <input {...field.input} />
    {field.touched && field.error && <span><i className="fa fa-warning"></i> {field.error}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

And my `Field`:

```
<Field name="addressOne" type="text" placeholder="Address One" component={renderField} />
```

I'd like to be able to pass helper text directly to the `Field` so I can include it in `renderField`. The docs show that redux-form is extremely flexible, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to achieve this.

EDIT --

When I say "helper text", I mean some copy to guide the user. For example, on a date field I'd like to add text along the lines of "The selected date must be two business days from now" and on a select field it might be "please choose only one from the list". Obviously this would be different for each field.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "helper text"?

Comment: Absolutely - I've edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy: all props you pass to `Field` that aren't used by redux-form are simply passed on to the component. I've added helpText to your example to show you how it works.

```
const renderField = field => (
  <div className={field.touched && field.error ? 'invalid' : 'valid'}>
    <span>{field.helpText}</span>
    <label>{field.input.placeholder}</label>
    <input {...field.input} />
    {field.touched && field.error && <span><i className="fa fa-warning"></i> {field.error}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

And Field:

```
<Field name="addressOne" type="text" placeholder="Address One" component={renderField} helpText="This is my custom help text." />
```

This is noted as point 3 in the `Field` [documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.4/docs/api/Field.md/) for redux-form v6.

Comment: Ah - I probably should have tried that.. couldn't see the forest for the trees on this one.. many thanks!

Comment: One small point - with react 15.2 I get an `Unknown prop` error - I switched it to `field.input.helpText` and the error went away.